# How to write the sample COM Server in Visual D

Tags: com, d

I'm struggling to get a simple COM Server running in Visual D 2010. These are the steps I did so far:

1. Clean Visual D 2010 solution of type Dynamic Library (DLL)
2. I've copied *contents* of `dserver.d` into `dllmain.d`
3. I've copied file `chello.d` and `dserver.def` into the solution's source folder, as well as advapi32.lib and ole32.lib from the `<D install dir>\dmd2\windows\lib`.
4. I've added the copied file into the solution by right-clicking the project in the solution explorer and Add->Existing item...
5. Renamed file `dserver.def` into `dll.def`, overwriting existing project's file.
6. Applied a patch to the `chello.d` and `dllmain.d` (originally `dserver.d`) as written on [this forum thread](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/mqoxluonyjdtjxauaxnl@forum.dlang.org?page=2)
7. Build Debug. No errors.
8. Calling `regsvr32 COMServer.dll` returns these four message boxes:

[image]

then

[image]

then

[image]

and finally

[image]

I am still unable to access the COM object from VBA. And referencing the DLL directly (by Browse... button and pointing to the COMServer.dll) fails with "Can't add a reference to the specified file."

Comment: check [Modern COM Programming in D](http://lunesu.com/uploads/ModernCOMProgramminginD.pdf)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella great presentation. Correct me if I'm wrong: there's nothing on COM Server in D in this presentation. There are examples of how D can be used as a COM client only.

Comment: sorry, rereading it I think you're right. The only thing I can find [about COM server is here](http://dlang.org/dll.html#com). There is an example in the "samples" folder in the DMD2 compiler (look for dserver.d)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella Yes, they are. I'm still struggling to get them working. I can build the sample .dll alright, but the file itself appears not to be a valid COM server. I'll update the question.

Comment: Looks like you need to add Advapi32.lib and ole32.lib to your project. (I don't know how to do that on visual D, but these are regular Windows libs, so it should be there, just need to add it to the build command). Then it should compile and you can try it.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I think I've made it, but I've got other problems; I've updated the question

Comment: In the sample folder, there's a dserver.def file that lists the exports. Did you use that in your project too? (I'm actually new to COM myself btw...)

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I did now ;-) But it doesn't work, simple adding to the project generates an error `Error 30: Unexpected End of File`. I'll add the contents of this file in case, its contents got broken got incompatible over time.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I've updated the question to reflect your idea. Maybe the Visual D doesn't understand, that this is my dll export file. Maybe I need to add this file to same special place? And thank you :-).

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Finally I've manage to build it. Unfortunately, the dll does not register. I've updated the question once again.

Comment: It says "LIBRARY dserver" in there, like the example, but your other thing says LoadLibrary("COMServer")  - are you sure you are loading/creating the right file? It might be generating dserver.dll instead of comserver.dll.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe good point. It appears that I've mistyped the def file in the question, it was `LIBRARY "COMServer.dll" from the very beginning...

Comment: Hmm, I'm having a fair amount of success with the example program now (running as administrator in Windows Vista)... another maybe stupid question, but are you in the Debug folder when you call regsrv32? Your build script is putting the dll in there rather than bin...

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Yes. I am in the debug folder, when I call the regsrv32. Otherwise the error I get would be `The specified module could not be found`. I use Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

I took another look at the forums and the problem with the samples seems related to TLS on Windows XP. I posted a (somewhat hacky) solution to it here:

http://forum.dlang.org/thread/mqoxluonyjdtjxauaxnl@forum.dlang.org?page=2

Comment: the comment thing is too long there... What's your VBA code look like? I just tried the sample from windows scripting host jscript: `WScript.CreateObject("Hello1.0");` and it failed because the sample doesn't implement IDispatch ("the object does not support automation" so QueryInterface failed). Maybe it is the same with vba.

Comment: well, I implemented IDispatch (sort of, just barely enough to work) and it worked from JScript now (currently on Windows 7). Took a fair amount of stuff since the phobos windows headers don't describe IDispatch, so i had to use the extra win32 download... and modify them too. But I'm feeling pretty good about this now, I'll clean it up at some point today and post a zip for you to look over with everything needed to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide you with a working answer. It looks like this was a year ago, I was trying to get an example of using a [COM server](https://github.com/JesseKPhillips/Juno-Windows-Class-Library/tree/comserver/examples/com/server) working. This uses [Juno](https://github.com/JesseKPhillips/Juno-Windows-Class-Library) (not 64bit ready), has nothing to do with Visual D, and most importantly I couldn't get to work. The issue I hit was related to registering the server ("side-by-side configuration is incorrect").

My qualifications for COM are all there in the history of Juno (so not much of any). If you're more familiar with COM you may get further, if it doesn't compile for the latest DMD let me know (2.064 isn't out yet anyway).